# Custom access control to REST endpoints in a Spring Boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

First of all, I know about `@PreAuthorize` annotations and about [Expression based access control](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.5.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#el-access).

For the sake of learning (as well as for many reasons), what I would like to have is this:

- Users are authenticated and their roles are provided by an LDAP directory and populated into the Principal object when they authenticate. This works, as in "it is currently in place in a project".
- An annotation (chosen to be `@AccessControl`) implements the paradigm that access control is entirely tied to roles. The annotation can be set on a class/type (the REST controller), in which case it applies to any method on which there's not also another such annotation, or on a method (a REST endpoint). The deepest annotation always wins, whether it is restricting or relaxing the authorization constraint.
- The access control logic, which is a bit more complex than what I could get from the expression based access control, would be enforced by another piece of code. It is also a bit more maintainable but I guess this is only in my eyes.

As an example, a controller would have, except for an `@AccessControl` annotation over a method, endpoints that can only be accessed by users with ADMIN in their list of roles:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@AccessControl({ Roles.ADMIN })
public class AdminController {
...
}
```

My current indecision, after reading a lot these past days is more about whether to write a custom request filter or rather an AOP advice.

With a custom request filter, I find myself unable (for the moment) to determine which method of which controller the request is going to be mapped to. The annotations are out of my reach.

With an AOP advice, I don't know (yet) how to reply to the client with a 403 Forbidden status.

My questions stem directly from these two points:

- How can I get the controller method that will be called for a client request?
- How can I return an HTTP status code from an AOP advice and **effectively end** the processing of the request when the client is not authorized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out to be much simpler than I initially thought and I completed it in less than a day, using the AOP option.

This is the code of the `AccessControl` annotation, comments removed:

```
@Documented
@Inherited
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ TYPE, METHOD })
public @interface AccessControl {

    public String[] value() default {};

}
```

It can be placed either on a controller (see my original post/question) or on a controller method:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/admin")
@AccessControl({ Roles.ADMIN })
public class AdminController {


    // This endpoint has open access: no authorization check will happen.
    @AccessControl
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DummyDto getNoCheck(@PathVariable Integer id) {

        return service.get(id);
    }

    // This endpoint specifically allows access to the "USER" role, which is lower 
    // than ADMIN in my hierarchy of roles.
    @AccessControl(Roles.USER)
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DummyDto getCheckUser(@PathVariable Integer id) {

        return service.get(id);
    }

    // The authorization check defaults to checking the "ADMIN" role, because there's
    // no @AccessControl annotation here.
    @RequestMapping(value = "{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public DummyDto getCheckRoleAdmin(@PathVariable Integer id) {

        return service.get(id);
    }

}
```

In order to perform the actual verification, two questions must be answered:

- first, which methods are to be processed?
- second, what is checked?

**Question 1: which methods are to be processed?**

To me, the answer was something like "all REST endpoints in my code". Since my code lies in a specific root package, and since I'm using the RequestMapping annotation in Spring, the concrete answer comes in the form of a Pointcut specification:

```
@Pointcut("execution(@org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping * *(..)) && within(my.package..*)")
```

**Question 2: what exactly is checked at runtime?**

I will not put the entire code here but basically, the answer consists in comparing the user's roles with the roles required by the method (or its controller if the method itself bears no access control specification).

```
@Around("accessControlled()")
public Object process(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
    ...
    // Get the roles specified in the access control rule that applies (from the method annotation, or from the controller annotation).
    // Get the user roles from the UserDetails previously saved when the user went through the authentication process.
    // Check authorizations: does the user have one role that is required? If no, throw an exception. If yes, don't do anything.
    // No exception has been thrown: let the method proceed and return its results.
}
```

What was bothering me in my initial thinking was the exception. Since I already had an exception mapper class that bears the `@ControllerAdvice` annotation, I just reused that class to map my specific `AccessControlException` to a 403 Forbidden status code.

For retrieving the user's roles, I used `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()` to recover the authentication token, then `authentication.getPrincipal()` to retrieve the custom user details object, which has a `roles` field that I normally set up during the authentication process.

The code above is not to be used as-is (for instance, path mapping collisions will happen), but this is just to convey the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

I want to provide an approach you can use if you want to follow the AOP advice root:

Concerning this point if using AOP:

> How can I return an HTTP status code from an AOP advice and
>   effectively end the processing of the request when the client is not
>   authorized? **solution:**

In your aspect class, using at Around Advice kindly do the following:

```
@Around("execution(* net.my.package.AdminController.*(..)) && args(.., principal)")
public ResponseEntity<?> processRequest(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Principal principal) {
    final String controllerMethodName = joinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    LOGGER.info("Controller Method name : {}", controllerMethodName);
    final boolean isAuthSuccessful = authenticationService.authenticate(principal);//Pass auth details here
    if(!isAuthSuccessful) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN).body("Request declined"); //End request if auth failed
    } else {
        try {
            return (ResponseEntity<?>)joinPoint.proceed(); //Continue with request
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            LOGGER.error("Error In Aspect :", e);
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("failed request");
        }
    }
}
```

Well, the above code has comments addressing the challenges you are facing. But for this code to work ensure to do the following:

1. Make Sure all your controller methods you want to intercept do return ResponseEntity
2. You can change the @Around aspect to use a Point cut with value of @annotation for your @AccessControl annotation and you are free to chain the conditions in the @Around aspect
3. Make sure you find a way to pass data to this aspect so that you have a way to validate user credentials